# Delegate with ref parameter

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, delegates, ref

Is there any way to maintain the same functionality in the code below, but without having to create the delegate? I'm interfacing with a 3rd-party API that contains a number of various DeleteSomethingX(ref IntPtr ptr) methods and I'm trying to centralize the code for the IntPtr.Zero check.

```
private void delegate CleanupDelegate(ref IntPtr ptr);

...

private void Cleanup(ref IntPtr ptr, CleanupDelegate cleanup)
{
    if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        cleanup(ref ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: What's wrong with creating the delegate?

Comment: Are you sure the third party API doesn't handle a null pointer as a NOP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean without declaring the delegate type, then probably not; very few (if any) inbuilt delegates use `ref`; but you could make it generic:

```
delegate void ActionRef<T>(ref T value);
```

I'm not sure this saves much though. There may *also* be some tricks here with extension methods, but it is hard to tell without more detail.