# Better way of organizing enum items other than switch?

Tags: c#, enums

So I have this bit of code that works just fine but, dear god, is it hard to look at. I am almost positive that there is a better way of writing this bit.

So basically I have a bit of data in a byte array that may or may not be a complete packet of data. The first few bytes are read as an Int32 which is the title of the Packet. It directly casts to my enum of the packets.

So for now I have my packets setup like this:

```
class SomePacket : Packet
{
  PacketType type = PacketType.SomePacket;

  public override Packet ReadPacket(ref buffer)
  {
    //Return if the buffer has all the data for this packet.
  }
  ...
}
```

But this essentially leads me to have to do this:

```
    public abstract Byte[] CreateSendBuffer();

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads and removes from buffer to make a packet.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer">Buffer used to try to create a packet.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Packet ReadBuffer(ref List<Byte> buffer)
    {
        if (buffer != null)
        {
            if (buffer.Count > sizeof(Int32))
            {
                Byte[] backupBuffer = buffer.ToArray();
                try
                {
                    Packet returnPacket = null;
                    Int32 packetType = TakeInt32(ref buffer);

                    switch ((PacketType)packetType)
                    {
                        case (PacketType.VerifyInfo_s):
                            returnPacket = VerifyInfo_s.ReadPacket(ref buffer);
                            break;

                        case (PacketType.Ping_sp):
                            returnPacket = Ping_sp.ReadPacket(ref buffer);
                            break;

                        case (PacketType.GameInfo_p):
                            returnPacket = GameInfo_p.ReadPacket(ref buffer);
                            break;

                        case (PacketType.DayPhase_p):
                            returnPacket = DayPhase_p.ReadPacket(ref buffer);
                            break;

                        case (PacketType.AddPlayer_p):
                            returnPacket = AddPlayer_p.ReadPacket(ref buffer);
                            break;

                        case (PacketType.Player_Visible_p):
                            returnPacket = Player_Visible_p.ReadPacket(ref buffer);
                            break;

                        case (PacketType.Player_Movement_s):
                            returnPacket = Player_Movement_s.ReadPacket(ref buffer);
                            break;

                        case (PacketType.Player_Movement_p):
                            returnPacket = Player_Movement_p.ReadPacket(ref buffer);
                            break;

                        case (PacketType.Player_Health_p):
                            returnPacket = Player_Health_p.ReadPacket(ref buffer);
                            break;

                        default:
                            DebugLogger.GlobalDebug.LogNetworking("Invalid packet header!");
                            throw new InvalidPacketRead();
                    }

                    if (TakeByte(ref buffer) == END_PACKET)
                        return returnPacket;
                    else
                        throw new InvalidPacketRead();
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e) //Not enough data yet to make a full packet.
                {
                    DebugLogger.GlobalDebug.LogNetworking("Packet not large enough yet." + e.ToString());
                    buffer = backupBuffer.ToList();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What way could I achieve this without the horrible mess of a switch?

Comment: Statically built `Dictionary<MyEnum, Action>`?

Comment: I prefer the switch statement.  It's incredibly clear whats happening, it's easy to maintain, and appears it would be easy to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get down to this level, code gets messy. It just does; and you have to learn to live with it.

That being said, you could define a `Dictionary<PacketType, Func<byte[], Packet>>` and build it up like this:

```
var parseMethods = new Dictionary<PacketType, Func<byte[], Packet>>();
parseMethods.Add(PacketType.VerifyInfo_s, VerifyInfo_s.ReadPacket);
...

returnPacket = parseMethods[(PacketType)packetType](buffer);
```

Is that *really* any better? Maybe, maybe not, but if you really have a thing against `switch` its the way to go.

Comment: Can you do that without lambdas, considering `ReadPacket` has a `ref` parameter?

Comment: What lambda expression?

Comment: I mean passing the delegate of `VerifyInfo_s.ReadPacket` directly. I would have written it like `parseMethods.Add(PacketType.VerifyInfo_s, () => VerifyInfo_s.ReadPacket(ref buffer);`, and the type of would be `Dictionary<PacketType, Func<byte[]>` because of the `ref` keyword.

Comment: @Mephy Yeah, I just used a generic delegate, not a lambda. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884061/delegate-with-ref-parameter You can create your own if the generic wouldn't work. I tried to match my example based on your code, sorry if I made a mistake. Same idea though.